# HTTP request redirections vulnerability does not detect with SonarLint plugin and SonarQube server

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Once we performed the static code analysis with sonarCube and SonarLint eclipse plugin,non of them could detect a vulnerability in below code segment . But this has defined as a vulnarability under the rules of sonarsource web site.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
  String location = req.getParameter("url");
  resp.sendRedirect(location); // Noncompliant
}
```

Reference
https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-5146

Answer (score 0):

This rule, along with other security-related rules, is available with SonarQube Developer Edition and above.

Refer the answer to the question in [SonarSource Community](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/http-request-redirections-vulnerability-does-not-detect-with-sonarlint-plugin-and-sonarqube-server/35148) by [Jean-Baptiste](https://community.sonarsource.com/u/JBL_SonarSource)